# Get HTML form array values in C#

Tags: c#

I am a PHP programmer, need some code to do in C#.net a reporting tool.

I am sending this form to ASP.NET

```
<input type="text" name="para[a]" value="A">
<input type="text" name="para[b]" value="B">
```

in PHP I am able to get these values by a simple loop

```
if(isset($_POST['para'])){
   foreach($_POST['para'] as $key => $val){
        echo 'Name '.$key.', Value = '.$val;
   }
}
```

but in C#.net I am unable to do anything like this, I googled but no reference is found

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    Response.Write(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
}
```

This C# code telling me all keys, but not as an form of array.

Any help?

Comment: this is not a duplicate, the duplicate question is asking to get all posted values, I am asking for specific array only

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325456/posting-a-string-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a subset of keys that begin with your specific prefix.
Or filter out the keys that don't begin with the prefix.

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    if (keys[i].StartsWith("para") {
        Response.Write(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
    }
}
```